# Python plyfile vs pymesh

Tags: python, ply-file-format

I need to read, manipulate and write PLY files in Python. [PLY](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) is a format for storing 3D objects. Through a simple search I've found two relevant libraries, [PyMesh](http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [plyfile](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile). Has anyone had any experience with either of them, and does anyone have any recommendations? `plyfile` seems to have been dormant for a year now, judging by Github.

I know this question instigates opinion-based answers but I don't really know where else to ask this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have succesfully used `plyfile` while working with pointclouds.

It's true that the poject had not presented any activity from a long time, but It meets its purpose.

And is not like the fact of parsing a ply file were something that allows you to recreate yourself by adding new features.

On the other hand `PyMesh` offers you many other features besides parsing ply files.

So maybe the question is:

Do you want to just 'read, manipulate and write PLY files' or are you looking for a library that provides more extra features?

What made me choose `plyfile` was that I'm able to incorporate it to my project by just copying 1 source file. Also I wasn't interested in any of the other features that PyMesh offers.

---

### Update

I ended writing my own functions to read/write ply files (supporting ascii and binary) because I found the plyfile source code a little messy.

If anyone is interested, here is a link to the file:
[ply reader/writer](https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/pyntcloud/io/ply.py)

Comment: Yours is 3 times faster in reading (let alone that you're putting the data straight into a pandas' DataFrame, which is so convenient)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Glanced at your code; it's worth noting you don't support writing color.

Comment: @AndrewWagner it actually support writing color, normals and other scalar fields. There is even a test for that: https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/tests/integration/io/test_to_file.py#L15

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia your code is great, but one small documentation hickup; in the docstring of your write_ply function you mention points & mesh should be ndarray objects while you actually expect dataframes

Answer (score 12):

As of (2020 January).

None, use open3d. It's the easiest and reads .ply files directly into numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

# Read .ply file
input_file = "input.ply"
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file) # Read the point cloud

# Visualize the point cloud within open3d
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd]) 

# Convert open3d format to numpy array
# Here, you have the point cloud in numpy format. 
point_cloud_in_numpy = np.asarray(pcd.points)
```

References:

- http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/visualization.html
- http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/working_with_numpy.html

Comment: I've now used both `plyfile` and Open3D. The nice thing about `plyfile` is that it's extremely lightweight. I don't think Open3D is suitable as and answer to what I've asked, because it's very heavy-weight and does much more than just reading and writing PLY files. I've also used Open3D for a bunch of other things, and I would thoroughly recommend anyone *against* it. Its documentation isn't very good and it's just generally awkward to use.

Comment: Update lines 5 and 7 as: `o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file)` and `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])`

Comment: This should be the correct the answer.  The reason is because plyfile is... extremely slow when it comes to very large PLY files.  I had a file with 24 million 3D points, and plyfile was taking minutes, while it took Open3D just a few seconds.

Comment: Open3D does not have the version for Python3.10 yet.

Answer (score 5):

I've just updated [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) to support PLY as well, next to about 20 other formats. Install with

```sh
pip install meshio
```

and use either on the command line

```sh
meshio convert in.ply out.vtk
```

or from within Python like

```py
import meshio

mesh = meshio.read("in.ply")
# mesh.points, mesh.cells, ...
```

Comment: There is no doc. It is really hard to use this package.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled my own ascii ply writer (because it's so simple, I didn't want to take a dependency). Later, I was lazy and took a dependency on plyfile for loading binary .ply files coming from other places. Nothing has caught on fire yet.

A thing to mention, for better or worse, the .ply format is extensible. We shoehorned custom data into it, and that was easy since we also wrote our own writer.